# Convert List<T> to dynamic

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic, clr

We have a generic output model with a field Data in it. The field is of type **dynamic**.
By design, it can be anything - a list, an object, etc. Now imagine I have a list of objects:

```
List<Person> personsList = personsProivder.GetPersons();
```

and want to assign it to this Data filed. How do I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: You can simply cast it to a dynamic, like so `dynamic dynamicPersonsList = (dynamic) personsProvider.GetPerson();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
public class PersonProvider
{
    public List<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return new List<Person>
        {
            new Person(1, "Simon"),
            new Person(2, "Bashir")
        };
    }
}

public class OutputModel
{
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var personProvider = new PersonProvider();
var outputModel = new OutputModel();

outputModel.Data = personProvider.GetPersons();
```

Works just fine!